# Twitter count update event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Twitter's button has counter.
How can we catch count update? Like in Facebook (FB.Event.subscribe)
jQuery can't get content of the button, coz it's iframe of external site.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a way, unless the iframe's url changes. What have you checked for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access iframes with other domain's content.
You should have to check twitter's api to get this count number

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: dev.twitter.com says: 
"In this early stage of the Tweet Button the count API is private. This means you need to use either our javascript or iframe Tweet Button to be able to render the count." so, how can we render it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the count API is still private according to the FAQ http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#count-api.

The private call returns JSON with count and url e.g.
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://google.com

Hopefully twitter soon allows us to get this count via a public API.